# AngularFire Database Object Exists Returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I am checking if an object exists in Firebase. I am using typescript with "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8" package. When checking if the object exists, I use this method below but  I returns `undefined`.

```
let isExists = this.myservice.isExists(order.$key);
console.log(isExists)
```

Returns `undefined`

```
  isExists(orderKey:string) {
    let urlOrRef = `/orders/${orderKey}`;
    const orderRef = this.af.database.object(urlOrRef, { preserveSnapshot: true });
    orderRef.subscribe(data => {
      if(data.val()==null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

So I tweak the method a little bit to explicitly set a variable to a boolean value and return that variable.

```
  isExists(orderKey:string) {
      let exists = false;
    let urlOrRef = `/orders/${orderKey}`;
    const orderRef = this.af.database.object(urlOrRef, { preserveSnapshot: true });
    orderRef.subscribe(data => {
      if(data.val()==null) {
        exists = false;
      } else {
        exists = true;
      }
    });
        return exists;
  }
```

Returns `true` or `false` which I was expecting.

I need understanding why the first method will return `undefined`. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Code is only code, but incomplete code is not a code. Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't understand how this becomes an incomplete code?

Comment: Ok. Let me add more details to the question.